# Accessing Pivotal Tracker with token in C# with RestSharp

Tags: c#, https, restsharp

I am trying to pull info from my Pivotal Tracker account via the token they give you. I am using RestSharp and C#. Here is my code.

```
using System;
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;

namespace RestTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://www.pivotaltracker.com/");
            string MyToken = "2a..7";
            var jwt = new JwtAuthenticator(MyToken);
            client.Authenticator = jwt;


            RestRequest getRequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
             getRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            //  getRequest.AddHeader("X-TrackerToken", MyToken);

            var request = new RestRequest("/projects", DataFormat.Json);

            var response = client.Get(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.ContentType.ToString());
            foreach (var header in response.Headers)
            {
                if (header.Name == "Status")
                    Console.WriteLine(header.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

application/json; charset=utf-8
406 Not Acceptable

if I change the rest request to say "abc" I get a 404 as expected.
Has anyone gotten information from Tracker with C#?

Thanks

Comment: Note that you have a double `/`. Once at the end of the base URL, once as part of the `/projects` request endpoint. Also, as far as I can tell from the documentation, the token should be passed as a header and you shouldn't be using the `JwtAuthenticator`.

Comment: I am not sure why do you need to add the accept header yourself. RestSharp adds whatever it can handle.